# Set ansible connection differently according to given condition

Tags: ssh, ansible, connection

I have a playbook that, for one of the hosts, how I need to connect differs according to whether certain tasks have previously succeeded.

In this specific case there's a tunnel between two of them, and one routes all its traffic over that tunnel, so once configured I need to use the other as a jump box in order to connect - but I can imagine many other circumstances where you might want to change connection method mid-playbook, from as simple as modifying users/passwords.

How can I have a conditional connection method?

I can't simply update with `set_fact`, since by the time I reach that task ansible will already have tried and possibly failed to 'gather facts' at the start, and won't proceed.

Answer (score 3):

The devil is in the details for such a question, for sure, but in general I think use of `add_host` will be the most legible way to do what you want. You can also change the `connection` on a per-task basis, or conditionally change the `connection` for the whole playbook against that host:

```
- hosts: all
  connection: ssh  # <-- or whatever bootstrap connection plugin
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - command: echo "do something here"
      register: the_thing

    # now, you can either switch to the alternate connection per task:
    - command: echo "do the other thing"
      connection: lxd  # <-- or whatever
      when: the_thing is success

    # OR, you can make the alternate connection the default
    # for the rest of the current playbook
    - name: switch the rest of the playbook
      set_fact:
        ansible_connection: chroot
      when: the_thing is success

    # OR, perhaps run another playbook using the alternate connection
    # by adding the newly configured host to a special group
    - add_host:
        name: '{{ ansible_host }}'
        groups:
          - configured_hosts
      when: the_thing is success

# and then running the other playbook against configured hosts
- hosts: configured_hosts
  connection: docker   # <-- or whatever connection you want
  tasks:
    - setup:
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following snippet as a role and invoke this role depending on the situation whether I need jumphost(bastion or proxy) or not. An example is also given in the comments. This role can add multiple hosts at the same time. Put the following contents in `roles/inventory/tasks/main.yml`

```
# Description: |
#   Adds given hosts to inventory.
# Inputs:
#   hosts_info:  |
#     (mandatory)
#     List of hosts with the structure which looks like this:
#
#     - name: <host name>
#       address: <url or ip address of host>
#       groups: [] list of groups to which this host will be added.
#       user: <SSH user>
#       ssh_priv_key_path: <private key path for ssh access to host>
#       proxy: <define following structure if host should be accessed using proxy>
#         ssh_priv_key_path: <priv key path for ssh access to proxy node>
#         user: <login user on proxy node>
#         host: <proxy host address>
#
# Example Usage:
#   - include_role:
#        name: inventory
#     vars:
#       hosts_info:
#         - name: controller-0
#           address: 10.100.10.13
#           groups:
#             - controller
#           user: user1
#           ssh_priv_key_path: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
#         - name: node-0
#           address: 10.10.1.14
#           groups:
#             - worker
#             - nodes
#           user: user1
#           ssh_priv_key_path: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
#           proxy:
#             ssh_priv_key_path: /home/user/jumphost_key.rsa.priv
#             user: jumphost-user
#             host: 10.100.10.13

- name: validate inventory input
  assert:
    that:
      - "single_host_info.name is defined"
      - "single_host_info.groups is defined"
      - "single_host_info.address is defined"
      - "single_host_info.user is defined"
      - "single_host_info.ssh_priv_key_path is defined"
  loop: "{{ hosts_info }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: single_host_info

- name: validate inventory proxy input
  assert:
    that:
      - "single_host_info.proxy.host is defined"
      - "single_host_info.proxy.user is defined"
      - "single_host_info.proxy.ssh_priv_key_path is defined"
  when: "single_host_info.proxy is defined"
  loop: "{{ hosts_info }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: single_host_info

- name: Add hosts to inventory without proxy
  add_host:
    groups: "{{ single_host_info.groups | join(',') }}"
    name: "{{ single_host_info.name }}"
    host: "{{ single_host_info.name }}"
    hostname: "{{ single_host_info.name }}"
    ansible_host: "{{ single_host_info.address }}"
    ansible_connection: ssh
    ansible_ssh_user: "{{ single_host_info.user }}"
    ansible_ssh_extra_args: "-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null"
    ansible_ssh_private_key_file: "{{ single_host_info.ssh_priv_key_path }}"
  loop: "{{ hosts_info | json_query(\"[?contains(keys(@), 'proxy') == `false`]\") | list }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: single_host_info

- name: Add hosts to inventory with proxy
  add_host:
    groups: "{{ single_host_info.groups | join(',') }}"
    name: "{{ single_host_info.name }}"
    host: "{{ single_host_info.name }}"
    hostname: "{{ single_host_info.name }}"
    ansible_host: "{{ single_host_info.address }}"
    ansible_connection: ssh
    ansible_ssh_user: "{{ single_host_info.user }}"
    ansible_ssh_extra_args: "-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null"
    ansible_ssh_private_key_file: "{{ single_host_info.ssh_priv_key_path }}"
    ansible_ssh_common_args: >-
      -o ProxyCommand='ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
      -W %h:%p -q -i {{ single_host_info.proxy.ssh_priv_key_path }}
      {{ single_host_info.proxy.user }}@{{ single_host_info.proxy.host }}'
  loop: "{{ hosts_info | json_query(\"[?contains(keys(@), 'proxy') == `true`]\") }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: single_host_info
```